# Can't identify this component from a Lancer Monitoring System DW101E

Tags: identification, components

I'm trying to reverse engineer this system to try to read an adressable transducer.
In this amp op configuration I don't know what this yellow component is supposed to do.

[image: marked component]

The component label is:
605
16 k
601

[image: label]

Any information or idea would much apreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's a capacitor, the "K" on the second row identifies it as from  Kemet.

Marking is value in pF, so 6800,000 = 6.8uF, voltage is 16V per the second row.

Third row is a manufactured date code.

[image]

Possible series - there's a few it could be -

https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_T2008_T494.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Its a tantalum capacitor probably 6.8uF, it appears that this cap is used as a filter to keep the voltage stable on the + terminal of the LM324